# Easiest way to replace values in multiple columns at once in R

Tags: r, gsub

I am trying to replace "*" in my dataframe with NA. I tried using gsub function as follows:

```
df = data.frame(x = c('*',2,3), y = c(3,3,5))

df[,1:2] = apply(df[,1:2], 2, function(x) gsub('*',NA,x))
```

Although there is only one * in my dataframe but gsub replaces all the data with NAs! It seems gsub has a problem with *. I thought this is the easiest way to replace * with NA in my dataframe but it failed. Anyone has a better idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `fixed = TRUE`:

```
df[,1:2] = apply(df[,1:2], 2, function(x) gsub('*',NA,x,fixed = TRUE))
```

`*` is used as a `regular expression` otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

And you can skip the apply function and just directly look for `*`:

```r
df <- data.frame(x = c('*',2,3), y = c(3,3,5))
df
#>   x y
#> 1 * 3
#> 2 2 3
#> 3 3 5

df[df[,]=="*"] <- NA
df
#>      x y
#> 1 <NA> 3
#> 2    2 3
#> 3    3 5
```

<sup>Created on 2021-01-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

And the `df[ , ]` is unnecessary so `df[df=="*"] <- NA` will suffice.